# Manually allocating memory for a struct

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, struct

So I am working on a project in C where we need to implement malloc and free (meaning, we CANNOT use any C memory management functions such as malloc() or free()). This is only a code snippet, but it includes all relevant parts.

```
struct block_header
{
    int size;
};

typedef struct FList_elem
{
    struct block_header * header;
    struct list_elem elem;
} FLelem;

void * manual_malloc(size_t size)
{
     freeBlock = (FLelem *) mem_sbrk(newsize);

     freeBlock->header = (struct block_header *) freeBlock;
     freeBlock->header->size = newsize;
}
```

When allocating a new "block" of memory, we represent it via a structure FList_elem. In order to "allocate memory" for the struct, we point it at a memory address returned by mem_sbrk (works just like sbrk()). My question is, how do we establish memory for variables like size? Initially it's address is 0x0, and so assignments or references to it cause seg faults. Does it need to be a pointer so that we can set it's address, and then the value?

Comment: Instead of taking it as a pointer, just include it in your `struct FList_elem` as an object. That way you'll have one main pointer from which you can get direct access to various attributes of the block structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your original code, which stores a *pointer* to `block_header` inside the `FList_elem` structure, you can just embed the whole `block_header` structure inside the `FList_elem` structure:

```
struct block_header
{
    int size;
};

typedef struct FList_elem
{
    /* OLD code: struct block_header * header; */

    /* Better code: block_header is embedded inside FList_elem structure */
    struct block_header header;
    struct list_elem elem;
} FLelem;
```

In this way, you don't need to allocate `block_header` separately: it's just there with the rest of `FList_elem` bytes.

And to set the size field (and any other attribute you may add to your block header) you can just do:

```
freeBlock->header.size = newsize;
```

Answer (score 0):

When allocating the requested size, you need to add the header elements - and the pointer to the next block (eventually - the size can be computed with pointer difference as a space optimization... if this is embedded staff they are 4 bytes per block saved).

Since I think there are some incongruences, I have reported here my interpretation (not tested) of what you are trying to do:

```
struct block_header
{
    int size;
};

typedef struct FList_elem
{
    struct block_header header; // removed a * here: size is in place
    struct Flist_elem *elem;    // added a * here: that's the pointer to the next block.
} FLelem;

FLelem *memory_list = 0; // added a pointer for the global list - right?

void * manual_malloc(size_t newsize)   // renamed as newsize here
{
     freeBlock = (FLelem *) mem_sbrk(newsize + sizeof(FLelem));

     freeBlock->header.size = newsize;
     freeBlock->header.elem = memory_list;
     memory_list = freeBlock;
     // inserted freeBlock at the head of memory_list;
     return (void*)(freeBlock+1); // +1 to skip the header as a return address
}
```

The caller of the function will have returned the space *after* the header.

Your `manual_free()` function will take as an argument this returned memory pointer, and it will need to subtract and go back a `freeblock` in memory in order to find the header and to release the block, and than you will need some sort of tree (bit tree) to keep of track of the holes left free... If you need to handle dynamic memory - and that's where it start being interesting.

Hope I have not done errors and that it's clear enough!

Comment: Careful with that code: C `malloc()` makes guarantees about the alignment of the allocated memory region, usually the allocation is aligned to a 16-byte boundary. This implementation makes no such guarantee.

Comment: The OP has already stated (*We are implementing free and malloc, so we CANNOT use C's memory management functions like free() and malloc()*) that he/she is implementing a malloc-like function, not having such facilities so I have tried to provide here a skeleton showing how malloc works, starting from his code. If he needs alignment, he has to implement it. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct st *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
```

Note that:

x must be a pointer

no cast is required

include appropriate header

Comment: Is this helpful for you ?

Comment: Just made an edit to make this clear: We are implementing free and malloc, so we CANNOT use C's memory management functions like free() and malloc()